# ServerManager not finding the correct Webserver

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, servermanager

Im using Microsoft.web.administration class to find all sites in IIS. It executes without any issue, but returning sites from another webserver. I guess its IIS express on my PC as part of VS. So how to specify my default webserver where the sites to be fetched.
Reference DLL was from **windwos\system32\inetsrv\Microsft.web.admnistration**
This is the code am using

```
 Dim sm As New ServerManager()

 For Each Sites In sm.Sites
    dd_sites.Items.Add(New ListItem(Sites.Name, Sites.Id))
 Next
```

It is not returning any sites from my IIS. It returns 2 sites which I have no idea from where it is taking. OS is Win 10